# Make Application level variable that changes on specific event

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, when we define Global Variable(i.e. in Application.rb file), it is Constant and we can't modifiy it. Is there any alternate available in Rails that i can use the Variable as Global variable in my Rails application and access and change it's value during execution ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you could put a function in your ApplicationController that sets a variable, then set up a `before_filter :your_def`. Set your variable up as an `@variable` and then have access/edit it any controller.

Comment: thanks for answer. But if i want to use it to some Concerns or files in the \lib directory ?